# AJAX File Download with custom header

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, download

I want to send a request to a URL which provides me a file download dialog box. At the same time the server needs certain parameters in the request header. I want to insert a custom header in the request and get a file in response. Is there any way we can achieve this?

Comment: What type of info are you adding to the request header? Concerning the response, you just send back what you want with something like this `Response.Clear();
            Response.ContentType = "application/text";
            Response.ContentEncoding = _ex.Encoding;
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", String.Format("attachment; filename={0}", _ex.FileName));
            Response.BinaryWrite(_ex.Output);
            Response.End();`

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24501358/how-to-set-a-header-for-a-http-get-request-and-trigger-file-download/24523253#24523253) is not an exact duplicate question, but is specifically for GET requests, but the answers there may be useful.

Answer (score 8):

Try using `a` element with `data-*` set to headers for request , `$.ajax()` with `headers` option set to `a` element `data-headers` object .

At `$.ajax()` `success` set `a` element `href` to response as `Blob` within `objectURL`, `download` attribute to `file.name` or temporary file name , call `.click()` on `a` element to activate "Save File" dialog .

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[type=button]").click(function() {
    // set `data-headers` object
    var el = $("[data-headers]");
    el.data("headers")["x-custom-headers"] = $("input[type=text]")[0].value 
      || el.data("headers")["x-custom-headers"];
    $.ajax({
      url: URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([$("textarea").val()], {
        type: "text/plain"
      })),
      type: "GET",
      // set `headers` to `a` element `data-headers` object
      headers: $("[data-headers]").data("headers"),
      beforeSend: function(jqxhr) {
        console.log(this.headers);
        alert("custom headers" + JSON.stringify(this.headers));
      },
      success: function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
        var file = new Blob([data], {
          "type": jqxhr.getResponseHeader("Content-Type")
        });
        console.log(data, file);
        $("textarea, input[type=text]").val("");
        $("a")
          .attr({
            "href": URL.createObjectURL(file),
            "download": file.name || "file-" + $.now()
          }).on("click", function() {
            $(this).remove()
          })
          .get(0).click();
      },
      error: function(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(textStatus, errorThrown)
      }
    });
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<textarea maxlength="5" placeholder="echo"></textarea>
<br>
<!-- set `x-custom-header` to `input type="text"` value -->
<input type="text" maxlength="5" placeholder="set request header" />
<br />
<input type="button" value="download" />
<!-- set default `x-custom-header` to "123" -->
<a data-headers='{"x-custom-headers":"123"}'></a>
```

Answer (score 6):

From what I understand is that you want to request a file from the web that requires a authentication header but can't be downloaded with a simple link.

What you need to do then is to make a ajax call with the authentication header to download the data as a blob. Then save the data from the client side

---

jQuery's ajax/get methods dosen't support the responseType = blob

So this example is using the latest [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) in Blink and Firefox. It also uses the [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) to save a client-side generated blob in versus ways to handle cross browser issues.

```
fetch("/", {headers: {"X-mashape-key": "XXXXXX-4-YYYYYY"}})
    .then( response => {
        // we can get the filename if the
        // response headers contains Content-Disposition
        var cd = response.headers.get("Content-Disposition");
        var name = cd && cd.match(/filename[^;=\n]*=((['"]).*?\2|[^;\n]*)/)[1];

        response.blob().then( 
            blob => window.saveAs(blob, name || "index.html")
        )
    })
```

It also use some new suger syntax that is available in es6 that can be transpiled to es5 with babel or traceur

If you don't include a [fetch polyfill](https://github.com/github/fetch) and need to support older browsers - Then you need to do it the old fashion way with XHR

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.responseType = 'blob';
xhr.open("get", "/");
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-mashape-key", "XXXXXX-4-YYYYYY");
xhr.send();
xhr.onload = function(){
    var cd = xhr.getResponseHeader("Content-Disposition")
    var name = cd && cd.match(/filename[^;=\n]*=((['"]).*?\2|[^;\n]*)/)[1];

    window.saveAs(xhr.response, name || "index.html")
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe I don't get your point.

What I think is like this:

```
//server xxx.php
//omit some code
echo '<a href="file_path" id="download">file_name</a>';

//browser
ajax({
    url: 'http://xxxx/xxx.php',
    success: function(html){
        //append to dom and TODO other manipulations
        $(dom).append(html);
        $('#download').trigger('click');
        $(dom).remove(html);
    }
})
```

Comment: I think the big issue is with the Request headers. How to customise them in the ajax call.

Comment: I think we may not set request headers, and ensure the response header include content-disposition:attachment.


But about the ajax file download question, I don't know why using this way.We can directly download files and it doesn't refresh the page.On the other hand, the XMLHttpRequest can not get the binary data

Comment: @Rex Huang you are wrong. xhr can get the binary data... just set the `xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer'`

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I checked in an old application I had and here is a sample. You'll need to adapt but the idea is here.
This first part is part of an Request interceptor attribute that is placed on the `WebMethod`. The whole interceptor is quite complex because it manages several cases.

```
int byteSize = 262144;
byte[] data = new byte[byteSize];

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(myfileName))
{
    _context.Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + myfileName+ "\"");
}

_context.Response.ContentType = DefaultContentType;
_context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Private);
_context.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1));
_context.Response.Buffer = false;
_context.Response.BufferOutput = false;
_context.Response.AddHeader("Content-length", myStreamSize.ToString());

try
{
    int counter = 0;
    int bytesRead = mystream.Read(data, 0, byteSize);
    while ((long)counter < myStreamSize|| bytesRead > 0)
    {
        counter += bytesRead;
        if (bytesRead < byteSize)
        {
            byte[] outBuf = new byte[bytesRead];
            Array.Copy(data, outBuf, bytesRead);
            _context.Response.BinaryWrite(outBuf);
        }
        else
        {
            _context.Response.BinaryWrite(data);
        }
        bytesRead = mystream.Read(data, 0, byteSize);
    }
}
finally
{
    mystream.Close();
    mystream.Dispose();
}
_context.Response.End();
```

This is the second part in the Javascript on the client side. We used ExtJS instead of jQuery.

```
downloadFile: function(url, getArgs) {
    if( !this.iframe )
    {
        this.iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
        this.iframe.className = "x-hidden";
        document.body.appendChild(this.iframe);
    }

    var args = Ext.urlEncode(getArgs);
    url = url + (args ? ("?" + args) : "");
    this.iframe.src = url;
}
```

The click of a button would call this function and give it the URL to the WebMethod and eventually extra args to pass.
The idea on the JS side is to create a hidden iFrame that would take the URL and would then prompt the user to download.

I hope it helps out