# JavaScript get file from server

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a following server endpoint that expects X-DOWNLOAD:yes request header parameter:

```
GET/POST example.com/download
```

If X-DOWNLOAD:yes is present server returns file to client. If no - redirects user to another page.

How to make a JavaScript call from client in order to get a file(set  X-DOWNLOAD:yes parameter) - show browser Save dialog ?

Comment: Nothing. I don't know how to do this in JavaScript

Comment: this may be what your after http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24501358/how-to-set-a-header-for-a-http-get-request-and-trigger-file-download

Comment: Server side is implemented

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add headers to the request do something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    headers: {
        "X-Download":"yes",
    }
    //OR
    //beforeSend: function(xhr) { 
    //  xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Download, "yes"); 
    //}
}).done(function(data) { 
    alert(data);
});
```

For download take a look at 
[Download a file by jQuery.Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545311/download-a-file-by-jquery-ajax)

Comment: Is it a right way to do file download or I should reimplement my server side?

Comment: @JuanMendes, jQuery is tagged. I believe it's fine

Comment: @adam Ha, I guess the mobile site doesn't show tags

Comment: @alexanoid regarding the download itself. It depends on the how the server is sending the file. Take a look at the reference question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545311/download-a-file-by-jquery-ajax