# Downloading file from server makes browser change page

Tags: javascript, c#, download

I am following the answer in this page ([How to set a header for a HTTP GET request, and trigger file download?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24501358/how-to-set-a-header-for-a-http-get-request-and-trigger-file-download/24523253#24523253)) in order to call from my client an mvc controller on the server. I need to use a manual ajax call instead of a library/plugin (like fileDownload) because I need to support bearer token.
The problem I face is that when I try to download the content, the controller is hit correctly and returns the data of type **FileDownloadResult**:

```
public sealed class FileDownloadResult : IHttpActionResult, IDisposable
    {
        private readonly MemoryStream _dataStream;
        private readonly string _fileName;
        private readonly string _path;
        private readonly string _mimeType;
        private readonly string _encoding;

        private string MimeType => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_mimeType) ? "application/octet-stream" : _mimeType;
        private string Encoding => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_encoding) ? string.Empty : _encoding;

        public FileDownloadResult(byte[] fileData, string fileName)
        {
            _dataStream = new MemoryStream(fileData);
            _fileName = fileName;
        }
}
...(other overrides methods for FileDownloadResult)...
```

The problem is that by using the code in the page linked at the beginning, my browser changes page. My code is the following on the client:

```
function downloadFile(url, data) {

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "GET",
        data: data,
        headers: {
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + appsecurity.getBearerTokenWithoutHeader().accessToken
        },
        success: function (data) {
            debugger;
            $("a")
                .attr({
                    "href": data.file,
                    "download": "file.txt"
                })
                .html($("a").attr("download"))
                .get(0).click();
            console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)));
        },
        error: function (jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(textStatus, errorThrown)
        }
    });
}
```

if I debug the returned **data** in the browser I see that the type is **document** .. I don't know if it helps but it's worth mentioning it. How can I solve the problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does it download the file though?

Comment: @NocNit no it doesn't unfortunately

Comment: This is not fully my area of expertise, but maybe the answer to this question helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26038856/how-to-return-a-file-filecontentresult-in-asp-net-webapi